Space for the cases/matrix environment and use of \dfrac into \[...\]
I have this MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[ 
\begin{cases} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} =& 2x(1 - y)=0 \iff x = 0 \quad \text{o} \quad y = 1 \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} =& (x^2 + y^2)(-1) + 2y(x^2 + y^2)(1 - y)=0
\end{cases}
 \]

\[H(x,y)= 
\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} \\ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} 
\end{bmatrix} \]


\[ 
\begin{cases} \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} =& 2x(1 - y)=0 \iff x = 0 \quad \text{o} \quad y = 1 \\[10pt]
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} =& (x^2 + y^2)(-1) + 2y(x^2 + y^2)(1 - y)=0
\end{cases}
 \]

\[H(x,y)= 
\begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} & \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} \\[10pt] \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} & \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} 
\end{bmatrix} \]
\end{document}



Using the cases environment and for bmatrix, to have a visible space I must force using the option (for example) [10pt]?


Why when I use the command \frac{}{} into \[ ...\] the fraction is little and to have a normal fraction must I use \dfrac?


your question is not very clear, but cells of matrices are set in textstyle not displaystyle so \dfrac forces a display style fraction and produces a larger result. You don't appear to have any fractions directly in \[. You don't have to use \\[10pt] but if you want to increase the row separation, you can. I'm not sure what answer you want for that?

@DavidCarlisle I hope that the question is more clear.

I answered the second question in the comment above, matrix elements are set in textstyle

My main suggestion is that you use \\[\jot] rather than \\[10mm] at the end of lines that should get some extra whitespace placed below them. (As @wipet has pointed out in a comment, \jot is a dimension register that's defined in both PlainTeX and the LaTeX kernel.) By default, \\[\jot] inserts 3pt of extra vertical whitespace below a row.  3pt is not a lot, but often it's all it takes to improve the appearance of some two-row or multi-row expression significantly. Use \setlength or \addtolength to modify the default amount.
A separate comment: I wouldn't use a cases environment here, since you're barely making use of that environment's machinery and generates unexpected (and likely unwanted) amounts of horizontal whitespace when used incorrectly. Instead, I'd use either an array environment (if \textstyle math is required) or an aligned environment, if \displaystyle math is required.

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'cases' and 'aligned' environments 
                     % and '\jot' macro (default: 3pt)

\begin{document}

\[ 
\begin{cases} 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} =& 2x(1 - y)=0 \iff x = 0 \quad \text{or} \quad y = 1 \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} =& (x^2 + y^2)(-1) + 2y(x^2 + y^2)(1 - y)=0
\end{cases}
\]

\[ 
\left\{ \begin{array}{@{} r @{{}={}} l @{}}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} & 2x(1 - y)=0 \iff x = 0 \quad \text{or} \quad y = 1 \\[\jot]
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} & (x^2 + y^2)(-1) + 2y(x^2 + y^2)(1 - y)=0
\end{array} \right.
\]


\[ 
\left\{ \begin{aligned} 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= 2x(1 - y)=0 \iff x = 0 \quad \text{or} \quad y = 1 \\[\jot]
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} &= (x^2 + y^2)(-1) + 2y(x^2 + y^2)(1 - y)=0
\end{aligned} \right.
\]

\medskip
\[ 
\begin{bmatrix} 
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} & 
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} \\ 
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} & 
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} 
\end{bmatrix} 
\quad\text{vs.}\quad
\begin{bmatrix} 
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} & 
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} \\[\jot] 
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} & 
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} 
\end{bmatrix} 
\]

\end{document}


\jot is dimen register declared in plain.tex and in the LaTeX kernel too.

@wipet - Thanks. I've been using LaTeX for more than 30 years, and way back when one had to load amsmath (or its predecessor) in order to get \jot. I'll update my answer to catch up to the present...

@Mico Thank you very very much for your answer.
